# Solve $x^2+5x+24=0$ mod $36$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve $x^2+5x+24=0$ mod $36$

So I have $x^2+5x+24\equiv 0$ mod $2^2\cdot 3^2$

SO I believe I need $x^2+x\equiv 0$ mod $2$ and $x^2+2x\equiv 0$ mod $3$

Which I determined that $0,1$ both work.

Then $f^\prime(x)=2x+5$

$f^\prime(0)=5$ and $f^\prime(1)=7$. So by hensel lemma there are solutions mod $4$

I'm not sure what to do now, am I supposed to lift to solutions mod $2^2$ and mod $3^2$?

I have $f(0+2t)=f(0)+2tf^\prime(0)\equiv 0 $ mod $4$

is $f(2t)=0+2tf^\prime(0)=2t(5)\equiv 0 $ mod $4$

then $10t\equiv 0$ mod $4$

which says $t=0$ which seems fine because $f(0)\equiv 0$ mod $4$ but I'm not sure I'm doing this right.

Im not sure how to deal with hensel lifting on numbers which aren't prime powers.

Comment: @NikhilSahoo So I can just do hensel lifting using the function mod $4$ and mod $9$ and then use CRT on every pair of solutions I find?

Comment: The modulus factors as $36 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2$. We can therefore solve each prime power
separately and then combine them using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. 

Mod 4 is small enough to check directly. We have $x^2+x\equiv0\bmod4 \implies x(x+1)\equiv0\bmod4$ which gives us two solutions of $0(\text{mod } 4)$ and $3(\text{mod } 4)$.

For the second prime power, we can first look at solutions modulo 3. We have $x^2+2x\equiv0\bmod3$ $\implies x(x+2)\equiv0\bmod3$ which gives us two solutions of $0(\text{mod } 3)$ and $1(\text{mod } 3)$.

Comment: As the derivative $x^2+5$ is non-zero at both of these roots, we know that they lift uniquely up to the roots modulo 9. We then analyze
$$\{3x(\text{mod } 9):0\le1\le2\}$$
$$\{1+3y(\text{mod } 9):0\le1\le2\}$$

and see that $6(\text{mod } 9)$ and $7(\text{mod } 9)$ are the unique solutions modulo 9. Now apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve this without Hensel lifting.

$x^2+5x+24\equiv0\bmod36\implies x^2+x\equiv0\bmod4$ and $x^2+5x+6\equiv0\bmod9$.

This means $x(x+1)\equiv0\bmod4$ and $(x+2)(x+3)\equiv0\bmod9$.

Note that $4|x(x+1)\implies 4|x$ or $4|x+1$, and $9|(x+2)(x+3)\implies 9|x+2$ or $9|x+3$,

because it is not possible for $2|x$ and $2|x+1$ or $3|x+2$ and $3|x+3$.

Anyway, can you take it from here?

Comment: Isn't the 4th line only true if you know $4$ is coprime to $x$ and $x+1$?

Comment: @AColoredReptile . One of $x,\,x+1$ is odd so one of $x,\,x+1$ is co-prime to $4.$ So if $4|x(x+1)$  then $4|x$ or $4|x+1.$